# Does anyone know any filters for better low quality video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, video-processing, video-encoding

So maybe my question can be closed, but anyway I'm researching and looking for a tool that can do the following with video files:

Here's an example of what I want:

When you put a low quality video on your TV and look into a mirror that reflects that image, it appears to be sharper, acting as a filter to improve the video.

I don't know if anyone has thought of this fact or if there is a software that does something similar. I know low quality video can't get any better, but why is there an improvement when looking in the mirror?

I appreciate if anyone can comment, as I'm not a professional in video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you search on the term 'upscale video' you should find many examples of techniques and solutions to do this.

Many more recent ones are AI driven.

One of the popular ones is: https://github.com/k4yt3x/video2x

Comment: This is interesting. It can solve the problem with low quality videos I have. But I believe that at the moment I don't have the technology to do this work. Do you know what is the minimum configuration that my computer needs to have to run this application with a relative amount of work time?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll likely have to test on your system to work that out.